# Microsoft Outlook (for mac) dismiss and/or snooze reminder via keyboard

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, macos-mojave

(Since updating to mojave?) sometimes when a reminder appears from my outlook calendar (the little popup a few minutes before an appointment starts), my mouse cursor disappears. It appears to still be present, and I can sometimes find the right things to click on based on hovers, but it's pretty annoying. I think I can get the cursor back once I snooze or dismiss the reminder. Is there a way to do dismiss or snooze the reminders with the keyboard?

I've tried tabbing around, but I don't think I can get the window as the active window, either that or I'm selecting the wrong things.

I'd love to see a keyboard shortcuts list which has shortcuts for snoozing or dismissing the content.

Comment: Upvoting for the question, not because I share the issue. I just don't understand developers obsession with only allowing the use of mice for tasks.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Keyboard shortcuts for Outlook for Mac](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/keyboard-shortcuts-for-outlook-for-mac-07ae68c8-b7af-4010-b225-324c04ac7335), there is no shortcuts for dismissing reminders in Outlook for Mac.

Considering that you are using Mojave, it is suggested to [manually install the latest version of Office for Mac](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=525133) and see the result. See:

[Microsoft Office support for macOS 10.14 Mojave](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/microsoft-office-support-for-macos-10-14-mojave-3593253c-95dc-4522-a8f7-8fb4fd16aff3)